# Just upgraded Hyper-V machine to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS server edition. Now keyboard is behaving oddly

Tags: keyboard, hyper-v

Hi I have just upgraded my Ubuntu VM to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, running in Hyper-V on Windows server 2019.

If I log into a session on the Ubuntu VM everything works as it should. However if I leave the VM window and come back any keystrokes I type are not displayed. As soon as I click away again and then back the previous keystrokes are shown.
So the machine appears to be working it is just something messed up with the keyboard.
Any ideas

Thanks Dave

Answer (score 0):

Installed latest Linux Integration Services, point 5 in Notes in this MS Learn article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-ubuntu-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v#notes

Seems to have worked